# Why does GNU ld resolve symbols differently when linking executables vs shared objects?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld, binutils

I have a trivial piece of C++ code that looks something like this:

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

int main(void) {
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile and link it (with gcc 4.8.1 and GNU ld 2.23.52.20130828) as follows:

```
$ g++ -o test test.cc -lboost_timer
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc2jP1jv.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.54.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

One solution is to explicitly mention `-lboost_system` on the command line, and that works. However, I can also do:

```
$ g++ -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries -o test test.cc -lboost_timer
```

According to the ld documentation "with --copy-dt-needed-entries dynamic libraries mentioned on the command line will be recursively searched, following their DT_NEEDED tags to other libraries, in order to resolve symbols required by the output binary", so this all makes sense: ld is figuring out from boost_timer that it also needs to link against boost_system in order to resolve all the symbols.

However, I realised that this also works:

```
$ g++ -fPIC -shared -o test test.cc -lboost_timer
```

Obviously, I've now generated a shared object rather than an executable. Apparently, though, ld was able to figure out that it needed to link the shared object against boost_system:

```
$ ldd test | grep boost_system
        libboost_system.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f385246e000)
```

So my question is this: why is symbol resolution different when building a shared object versus an executable? How is ld able to figure out that my shared object should be linked against boost_system without my specifying `--copy-dt-needed-entries`?

Comment: Have you tried with `-shared -z defs` ?

Comment: @CharlesBailey Adding `-z defs` to the shared build does cause it to break (`test.cc:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'`).

Looking at `-z defs` has also pointed me to `--[no-]allow-shlib-undefined` and that might actually explain what's happening... thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct answer to my question is in the `--[no-]allow-shlib-undefined` option to ld, I think. From the man page:

> The default behaviour is to report errors for any undefined symbols
>   referenced in shared libraries if the linker is being used to create
>   an executable, but to allow them if the linker is being used to create
>   a shared library.

Therefore, when I build with `-shared`, the symbols in boost_system are undefined, but the default behaviour of ld is not to care. It can be told to care:

```
$ g++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined -o test test.cc -lboost_timer
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6j1de3.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.54.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Similarly, we can tell it not to care when building an executable:

```
$ g++ -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -o test test.cc -lboost_timer
/tmp/ccUHoCIU.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cc:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
test.cc:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
test.cc:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But creating the binary fails without being able to define those symbols.

Thanks @CharlesBailey for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in the collect2 command that may be relevant. The different commands are compared at https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrfGw.jpg . The right hand side creates the shared library (-fPic -shared), the left is the normal compile.

Comment: this maybe a off-topic question. But your diff image looks interesting. can you please let us know where did you got that diff tool??